# File request to open not working in Django

Tags: javascript, django

The code written works perfectly fine when I run in browser, though I have left out certain parts of HTML code here (some textfields, forms etc) for better readability.

It works perfectly fine in browser but when I run the HTML as part of Django project in [venv][1] it simply refuses to get the file DOC_JSON.json(already created and available in the same folder).

**Is there anything I need to add for  XMLHttpRequest() to work in Django. It doesn't throw any error.**

````
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<body>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
                alert("Please Fill The Mandatory Fields !");

}

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var file_name = "Doc_JSON.json";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
   {
               var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
               document.getElementById("fname").value=     myObj.FirstName;
               document.getElementById("lname").value=     myObj.LastName;
               document.getElementById("addr").value=      myObj.Address;
               document.getElementById("phno").value=      myObj.PhoneNumber;
               document.getElementById("email").value=     myObj.EmailAddress;
               document.getElementById("ed").value=        myObj.Education;
               document.getElementById("techskill").value= myObj.TechnicalSkillset;
               document.getElementById("wrkexp").value=    myObj.WorkExperience;
               document.getElementById("Empauth").value=   myObj.EmploymentAuthorization;

               //Validating Mandatory Fields

             if ((document.getElementById("fname").value == null) || (document.getElementById("fname").value == "") ||
                 (document.getElementById("lname").value == null) || (document.getElementById("lname").value == "") ||
                 (document.getElementById("addr").value == null) ||  (document.getElementById("addr").value == "" )  ||
                 (document.getElementById("phno").value == null) || (document.getElementById("phno").value == "" )  ||
                 (document.getElementById("email").value == null) || (document.getElementById("email").value == "") ||
                 (document.getElementById("ed").value== null) || (document.getElementById("ed").value=="") ||
                 (document.getElementById("techskill") == null) || (document.getElementById("techskill") =="")||
                 (document.getElementById("Empauth").value == null) || (document.getElementById("Empauth").value ==""))
                {
                filled=false;
                document.getElementById("Subtn").disabled=true;
                //alert("Please Fill The Mandatory Fields !");
                //myFunction();
                setTimeout(myFunction, 100);
                }

                else
                {
                document.getElementById("fname").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("lname").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("addr").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("phno").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("email").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("ed").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("techskill").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("wrkexp").readOnly = true;
                document.getElementById("Empauth").readOnly = true;
                }

                function check()
                {
                 var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                 var textareas = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
                 var filled = true;

                for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++)
                 {
                if (inputs[i].type === "text" && !inputs[i].value) {
                filled = false;
                 }
                 }

                for (var j = 0; j < textareas.length; j++) {
                if (!textareas[j].value) {
                filled = false;
                }
                }

                 var phnoformat = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
                var emailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
              if (!(document.getElementById("phno").value).match(phnoformat))
              {
                            filled = false;
              }

            if (!(document.getElementById("email").value).match(emailformat))
            {
                          filled = false;
            }

                if (filled) {
                document.getElementById("Subtn").disabled = false;
                }
               }
                window.addEventListener("keyup", check);
                window.addEventListener("click", check);

                var phnoformat = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;
                var emailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
                 if (!(document.getElementById("email").value).match(emailformat))
                 {
                 document.getElementById("phno").style.background="#FE2E64";
                 }
                 if (!(document.getElementById("email").value).match(emailformat))
                 {
                             document.getElementById("email").style.background="#FE2E64";

                 }

}
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", file_name, true);
xmlhttp.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>```


  [1]: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html
````

Answer (score 0):

Where is the file located?

It should be under:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: can you explain more? sorry i'm so new to this stuff

Comment: Where is the file ```Doc_JSON.json``` stored? In which directory?

Comment: Actually it worked. Added static_dirs in settings and hardcoded the file path. Thanks a lot!